# Pop!_OS isn't reading .XCompose file

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, keyboard-layout, input-method, ibus

So I've been told that **IBus** can now work with **.XCompose** files and that I don't need to modify the **GTK_IM_MODULE** and **QT_IM_MODULE** to **xim** anymore, but without setting it to xim my GTK doesn't read my .XCompose file, GTK just ignores it. And I've also been told that xim have some issues and I should stay away from it. So how can I fix this issue without having to mess with xim ? I'm running **Pop!_OS 19.10 - GNOME 3.34.2** btw.
[image: My input method setup]